# How do I get a non lowercase string after quotes in the titlecase condition

Tags: c#, title-case

In my article titles, I use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(str.ToLower());` but I think, it is not working after double quotes. At least for Turkish.

For example, an article's title like this:

> KİRA PARASININ ÖDENMEMESİ NEDENİYLE YAPILAN "İLAMSIZ TAHLİYE"
>   TAKİPLERİNDE "TAKİP TALEBİ"NİN İÇERİĞİ.

After using the method like this:

```
private static string TitleCase(this string str)
{
   return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(str.ToLower());
}
```

`var art_title = textbox1.Text.TitleCase();` It returns

> Kira Parasının Ödenmemesi Nedeniyle Yapılan "İlamsız Tahliye"
>   Takiplerinde "Takip Talebi"Nin İçeriği.

The problem is here. Because it must be like this:

> ... "Takip Talebi"nin ...

but it is like this:

> ... "Takip Talebi"Nin ...

What's more, in the MS Word, when I click "Start a Word Initial Expense," it's transforming like that

> ... "Takip Talebi"Nin ...

But it is absolutely wrong. How can I fix this problem?

**EDIT:** Firstly I cut the sentence from the blanks and obtained the words. If a word includes double quote,  it would get a lowercase string until the first space after the second double quote. Here is the idea:

```
private static string _TitleCase(this string str)
{
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(str.ToLower());
}
public static string TitleCase(this string str)
{
    var words = str.Split(' ');
    string sentence = null;
    var i = 1;
    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        var space = i < words.Length ? " " : null;
        if (word.Contains("\""))
        {
            // After every second quotes, it would get a lowercase string until the first space after the second double quote... But how?
        }
        else
            sentence += word._TitleCase() + space;
        i++;
    }
    return sentence?.Trim();
}
```

**Edit - 2 After 3 Hours:** After 9 hours, I found a way to solve the problem. I believe that it is absolutely not scientific. Please don't condemn me for this. If the whole problem is double quotes, I replace it with a number that I think it is unique or an unused letter in Turkish, like alpha, beta, omega etc. before sending it to the `ToTitleCase`. In this case, the `ToTitleCase` realizes the title transformation without any problems. Then I replace number or unused letter with double quotes in return time. So the purpose is realized. Please share it in here if you have a programmatic or scientific solution.

Here is my non-programmatic solution:

```
public static string TitleCase(this string str)
{
    str = str.Replace("\"", "9900099");
    str = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(str.ToLower());
    return str.Replace("9900099", "\"").Trim();
}
```

`var art_title = textbox1.Text.TitleCase();`

And the result:

> Kira Parasının Ödenmemesi Nedeniyle Yapılan "İlamsız Tahliye" Takiplerinde "Takip Talebi"nin İçeriği

Comment: What's the meaning of this second `"` in `"Takip Talebi"Nin`? Is the second `"` not ending the quotation started by the first one or why isn't there a blank in between?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: This is not an issue with the Turkish `CultureInfo`, other languages behave equally. The second `"` indicates a new word. Maybe either get rid of it, reformat it, do a uncapitalisation for `"` surrounded by letters with no blanks via Regex or come up with your own `ToTitleCase()` alternative via extension method

Comment: @mjwills, Thank you very much. I edited my question 2 times.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, Microsoft documentation [ToTitleCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase?view=netframework-4.7.2) states that ToTitleCase is (at least currently) not linguistically correct. In fact, it is REALLY hard to do this correctly (see these blog posts of the great Michael Kaplan: [Sometimes, uppercasing sucks](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2006/08/18/706383.html) and ["Michael, why does ToTitleCase suck so much?"](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/03/04/384927.html)).

I'm not aware of any service or library providing a linguistically correct version.

So - unless you want to spend a lot of effort - you probably have to live with this inaccuracy.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the apostrophe or quote character with RegEx and replace the character after it.

For apostrophe

`Regex.Replace(str, "’(?:.)", m => m.Value.ToLower());`

or

`Regex.Replace(str, "'(?:.)", m => m.Value.ToLower());`